# module PySide6 not found

Tags: python, qt, visual-studio-code, pip, pyside6

I'm currently working with the PySide6 module.(vscode) But for some reason it doesn't work anymore,it worked before but it doesn't now. When I try to run my project this is the error I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6'
```

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox, QFileDialog
from PySide6.QtCore import QResource, QFile, QIODevice
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore
```

Updating pip, reinstalling PySide6, Updating PySide6, running my project differently, it all doesn't work... I still get the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6'`.
Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: Are you in a venv? Did you activate it and install PySide6 *there*?

Comment: Not sure what venv means, but I am working in vscode, and in tried to reinstall it in there.

Comment: try executing your script outside of vscode

Comment: doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the correct interpreter.

Then use command `pip install PySide6` in the terminal.